# missing .dependencies in user/ when bin/grav

Tags: grav

I'm trying to install Grav on Heroku following the learn.getgrav.org docs.

I've got the web app deployed successfully, however it tells me to bin/grav install.

I do that and it gives me the following output:

`ERROR Missing .dependencies file in user/ folder`

I do not know what to do at this point as it's happened everytime I've installed Grav.

Hope this will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this problem is all too common when copying files :(

hidden (dotted) files are not always copied.

```
.dependencies
.htaccss
```

using `ls -l -a` in the folder where you extracted the files originally Dowloads/grav I could see the files that were not copied to fix it

```
cp .dependencies .htaccss /var/www/grav/
```

When I install GRAV on my server each time, I always copy the Zip file to the server, unzip it in place, then remove the zip file - using this method I have never had a problem with the installing of GRAV

HTH Rich